# How to setup queue with redis in Cpanel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8, I send email notification to multiple users by laravel queue with redis. Now i want to setup this functionality in my cpanel. Although i enable redis in cpanel but show the error.

`Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`

Comment: You may need to contact your host or cPanel for support. I would suspect that their Redis integration has some sort of password in place; look around for credentials or connection details in the UI.

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion.